# Using Python/Pandas to extract data associated with each of the cities and save in separate excel sheet using loop or function

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, loops

```
data = {'city':['Austin TX', 'Austin TX', 'Austin TX', 'Columbus OH', 'Columbus OH', 'Columbus OH', 'Columbus OH', 'Dallas TX', 'Dallas TX' , 'Dallas TX', 'Dallas TX' , 'Dallas TX'],
        'a1':[20, 200, 300, 400, 1000, 500, 800, 900, 900, 1000, 200, 450], 'a2':[30, 100, 1000, 500, 400, 600, 340, 430, 230, 450, 670, 780]}
```

I would like to check if city from second row is same as first row and if it is, then I have to get the data for that city. The final output I need is separate data frame or excel sheet or csv containing data for each of the cities. For example, for Austin TX, there would be one excel sheet named 'Austin_excel' that contains data for Austin which will be first 3 rows of a1, a2 and city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want -

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
workbook = pd.ExcelWriter("City Data.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")

for city, city_data in df.groupby("city"):
    city_data.to_excel(workbook, sheet_name=city)

workbook.save()
```

The output looks like -

[image]

The data are in separate sheets of the Excel workbook as required.

Comment: Thank you, this is one of the output I wanted. is it also possible to put each of the cities data into different excel workbook with the name of cities as name of excel workbook. For example, instead of creating each tab within a workbook, I would like to save Austin TX data in workbook named report_austin, second workbook for Columbus OH in workbook named "report_columbus"

Comment: @Sue, yes you can. All you have to do is to replace the line `city_data.to_excel(workbook, sheet_name=city)` with something like `city_data.to_excel(r"report_{city.lower()}.xlsx")`. For this, you no longer need a `pd.ExcelWriter` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can export Pandas DataFrame to an Excel file using to_excel.

Here is a template that you may apply in Python to export your DataFrame:

df.to_excel(r'Path where the exported excel file will be stored\File Name.xlsx', index = False)
For instance:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Product': ['Desktop Computer','Printer','Tablet','Monitor'],
    'Price': [1200,150,300,450]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Product', 'Price'])

print (df)
```

Then you may got this:
[image]